# Timeout for an existing cache object .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am building an MVC web application, and I have a few objects in the cache inserted by the following statement:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("CacheKey", "CachedValue");
```

I know that I can add a timeout by using the following when inserting an item to the cache:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("CacheKey", "CachedValue", null, DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10000), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

However, my specific requirements are updating the cache timeout once the items have been inserted in the cache. 
So basically, I need to add a timeout to an existing item in the cache. How would I go about in doing that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fetch the item, add it back in with the timeout?

Comment: could you give me the code to do that? I can fetch the item by HttpContext.Current.Cache["CacheKey"] but how do I add a timeout to this object?

Comment: You have the code to add a timeout in your OP?

Comment: does it update the item in the cache if I do an insert again for the same key?

Comment: Yes it does, that should have been obvious really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my question. If I use the insert method, it updates an existing value if there is an object in the cache with the same key.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the show, but you could do the following, drop the cache and then re-cache with new data.
i.e HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(your cache id);

Hope it helps